# Load multiple Excel files with different schema into SQL Table

Tags: sql, ssis

I have three excel files with different structures. See below.

Table : 1
AuditID TransactionID   Date    Name    XXX XYZ

Table : 2
AuditID TransactionID   Date    Name    YYY

Table : 3
AuditID TransactionID   Date    Name    ZAAA    ZBBB    ZCCC

Output
AuditID TransactionID   Date    Activity    Activity_Value

The Activity column has all the non-matched column names from the above 3 tables, the Activity_Value column has the values of it.

How do i achieve this? The structure of the excel files will be changed on a daily basis.

With SSIS foreachloop, we can't achieve this because of non-matched columns of all the excel files. Any other solution for this?

Thanks in advance,
Pradeep

Comment: PowerBI has nothing to do with loading data into SQL Server. You *can* use SSIS and a foreach loop for this. If you can differentiate the files by name, you can use different loops with different filters. Better yet, put the files into different folders from the start. If you can't differentiate putting different files into different folders is probably the easiest solution

Comment: What does `The structure of the excel files will be changed on a daily basis.` mean? Why? How will you ever know what Column A does if it changes meaning every day? Without any example of the *files* and their names, people can't give concrete advice. It's not the *tables* that cause the problem

Comment: Hi Panagiotis Kanavos,

you are absolutely right. i have these 3 files with different structure. Then, I would receive different files with different structures by daily. We cannot do it in ssis foreach loop, as it supports only the same schemas.

Comment: everyone deals with different files, and they do it with foreach loops. It's not the *loop* that's the problem. The *data source* for a specific file has to have a stable structure. To make their life easier poeple make sure they use different folders for each file type or different filters. WIthout any info about the files, people can't post an answer